# Overriding libs onTouch listener

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm using `PhotoView` https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
It on it's own already implements an `OnTouchListener` on the `ImageView` you give it.

Here is my problem tho I need to implement a `OnLongTouchListener` as well and in it I need `X & Y coordinates` of the touch event. The problem is I cannot get those from `OnLongTouchListener->onLongClick(View ..)` which means I need to also implement my own `OnTouchListener` get the `X & Y` from `MotionEvent` put them in class variable than do my thing in `OnLongTouchListener`.

However my own OnTouchListener overrides PhotoViews listener removing the zoom & swipe functionality.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Observable;

import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

public class MapView extends Observable {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private PhotoViewAttacher photoView;
    private Matrix viewMatrix;

    protected ImageView view;
    protected Bitmap bitmap;

    public MapView(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        view = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.floorplan);

        photoView = new PhotoViewAttacher(view);
        viewMatrix = view.getImageMatrix();

        view.setOnTouchListener(new MapViewTouchListener());
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new MapViewLongTouchListener());
    }

    private class MapViewLongTouchListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.i("output", "Long press");
            return true;
        }

    }

    private class MapViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("output", "Touch");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Temporary solution. I created my own class and overrode the `onTouch` method. Turns out `PhotoViewAttacher` implements `OnTouchListener` so i was able to get it working just reimplementing the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to simply extend the `PhotoViewAttacher` class implement `OnLongClickListener` and pass it the `MotionEvent` from internal `onTouch` method.

```
private class ZoomableMapView extends PhotoViewAttacher implements OnLongClickListener {

  private MotionEvent event;

  public ZoomableMapView(ImageView view) {
    super(view);
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    this.event = event;
    return super.onTouch(view, event):
  } 

  public boolean onLongClickListener(View view) {
    // Access event.getX.getY... here
    ...
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for a long press, i think you want soemthing like this:

```
if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && event.getActionIndex()==0){
    mFingerTimeDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP &&     event.getActionIndex()==0 ){
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis()-mFingerDownTime) >= LONG_PRESS_TIME_MILLIS)
        //long press action
    else
        //short press action
}
```

Comment: Problem is when I set my own onTouch listener it overrides the one from PhotoView. : /

Answer (score 0):

Try return false in your listener. If listener event method returns true that means that event was handled and it will not propagate to view below.